# Why did Galileo pick "temperatura" to signify 'degree of heat or cold'?

Tags: terminology

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=temperature)  avouches that

> Sense of "degree of heat or cold" first recorded 1670 (Boyle), from Latin *temperatura*, used in this sense by Galileo.

But "degree of heat or cold" doesn't semantically appertain to *temperatura*, which originally signified "mixture" as quoted below. Why did Galileo pick this unrelated noun of *temperatura*?

> #### temper [OE]

> The verb *temper* was borrowed into
> Old English from Latin *temperāre* ‘mix, blend’.
> This seems originally to have meant ‘mix in due
> proportion’, and so may have been derived from
> Latin *tempus* ‘time, due time’ (source of English
> *temporary*). The noun *temper* was derived from
> the verb in the 14th century in the sense ‘mixture
> of elements’, and this led on in the 17th century
> to ‘set of mental traits’ (a meaning that has now
> largely passed to the derivative *temperament*
> [15]). The modern sense ‘ill humour’ emerged
> from this in the 19th century. Another meaning
> of Latin *temperāre* was ‘restrain oneself’, which
> has come through into the derivatives
> *temperance* [14] and *temperate* [14]. Other
> relatives include *distemper* and *temperature*.
>        *Tamper* probably originated as an alteration
> of *temper*.

> #### temperature [16]

> Like its relatives *temper* and
> *temperament*, *temperature* originally meant
> ‘mixture’ (Philemon Holland in 1601 wrote of ‘a
> temperature of brass and iron together’). The
> modern sense ‘degree of heat’ emerged in the
> late 17th century, and seems to have evolved
> from another early and now obsolete sense,
> ‘mild weather’. This reflected the ‘restraint’
> strand of meaning in the word’s ultimate source,
> Latin *temperāre*, which also survives in English
> *temperance* and *temperate*.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto. p 500 Left column.

[Temperament and Temperature: Are They Related? | Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/origin-of-temperament-and-temperature)

> Although *temperature* is rarely if ever used in these ways today, the implication of moderation likely influenced people to apply it as a word for the mildness of weather or climate,

Comment: Because of another meaning of Latin *temperāre*, as your quote mentions at the end.

Comment: From [temperamento](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/temperamento): nature, disposition, from Latin *temperamentum*. Used also to refer to climate ["per distinguer le mutazioni di caldo e freddo e la varietà de' temperamenti de' luoghi"](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Speciale:Ricerca?search=temperamenti&prefix=Racconto+istorico+della+vita+di+Galileo&fulltext=Cerca+in+questo+libro&fulltext=Search&ns0=1&ns102=1&ns110=1).